# Can Android kill my app while it is in the middle of a loop execution?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, kill-process

When `Android` decides to remove an application from the stack in order to free up some `RAM`, what happens if the application that is being destroyed is currently running some loop in the background? Will the loop be terminated amid execution or will the `VM` wait for it to finish?

Comment: In background means "not on the UI Thread"? Afaik there will be guaranteed some callbacks called but then it will be stopped. See application lifecycle on android developer site.

Comment: yes, but lets assume I am asking for both cases - in an IntentService, or a Service (but the user had forgotten to provide concurrency for it)

Comment: or a Runnable passed to an ExecutorService

Comment: or a BroadcastReceiver fired by an Alarm Manager

Comment: Generally you have to hold a wakelock to ensure that the process is not killed

Comment: But when it gets killed, if it is currently running a loop, is the loop interrupted, or the VM waits for it to finish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will the loop be terminated amid execution or will the VM wait for it to finish?

The loop is terminated, otherwise it isn't quite "killing".

Simple test:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    Log.i("LOOP", "Running");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }).start();
}
}
```

Swipe the app out from the recent apps.

Comment: Great, so If I am in the middle of deleting 200 local notifications in AlarmManager, or storing 200 products in the DB, this operation can be cut down in the middle? How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: _"...this operation can be cut down in the middle?"_ Yes. _"How do I prevent this from happening?"_ You can't "prevent" the system behaviour. But you can use a [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) (e.g. with ['START_STICKY'](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) flag) that re-starts after killing the app by the system.