# How long do Android worker threads last?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, worker-thread

I have seen some postings on this subject, but none of them have satisfactory answers.

Assume that I start a worker thread from my main (one-and-only) `Activity`, in its `onCreate()` method. Then I call `finish()` to cause the `Activity` to terminate.

At that point, the task it belongs to gets destroyed (since there are no longer any `Activity` in it). The app (and the process running it) may continue to exist, however, in empty "skeleton" form, so that it can be restarted quickly if desired (although it would be highly susceptible to being killed by the system).

Assuming the above is correct -- when is the worker thread killed? Is it only killed when the system actively destroys the process?

In my case, my worker thread exists as a listener for a Bluetooth connection; when received, it will fire up the desired `Activity` again. In this situation there is no actively running component (`Activity`, `Service`, `ContentProvider` or `BroadcastReceiver`). It seems to me that this should work, except that something is killing my worker thread.

I am aware that I could do this (and with less pain) by using a background `Service`. However, I'm curious about why this isn't working.

Thanks,
Barry

Comment: I believe that the Thread will only be killed automatically when the Linux process is destroyed.

Comment: _"It seems to me that this should work, except that something is killing my worker thread"_ This can only mean the [system terminated the app process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34463069/can-android-kill-my-app-while-it-is-in-the-middle-of-a-loop-execution). _"Is it only killed when the system actively destroys the process?"_ Correct (or if the `run()` method returns).

Comment: Agreed. The question then becomes, when is the process killed? My guess is that it is killed when there are no more running components, but I haven't seen that explicitly documented anywhere. More in my response to Oleg's BroadcastReceiver response, below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Android App lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/processes/process-lifecycle.html) has a nice example that is very on topic:

> A common example of a process life-cycle bug is a BroadcastReceiver
>   that starts a thread when it receives an Intent in its
>   BroadcastReceiver.onReceive() method, and then returns from the
>   function. Once it returns, the system considers the BroadcastReceiver
>   to be no longer active, and thus, its hosting process no longer needed
>   (unless other application components are active in it). So, the system
>   may kill the process at any time to reclaim memory, and in doing so,
>   it terminates the spawned thread running in the process.

In short, its really not very predictable if you thread would get a chance to run until termination or process will be killed beforehand, you should NOT definitely rely on any order/behavior.

Worth mentioning separately that its fairly easy to [leak](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/activitys-threads-memory-leaks.html) your activity along with thread even if you finish() it, but if its your last/only activity it does not change the picture

Comment: He only leaks the Activity if the Activity has a reference to it.  If his Thread doesn't reference the Activity in any way and is either a static inner class or a non-inner class, there is no leak of the Activity, but only of the references the Thread class holds.

Comment: he does not need to have explicit reference, its enough to say new Thread() {...} in onCreate to get implicit reference and boom

Comment: No it isn't.  That's true only if the Thread is a non static inner class.  Which your example is (its a non-static anonymous inner class), but does not need to be the case.  Static inner classes do not have a reference to the parent class.

Comment: Given that author did not show any code about threading I was clearly talking about my example, so i can't understand which part is 'No it isn't', sorry

Comment: @BarryHolroyd happy to help

Comment: @Oleg -- thanks for your comments. I think you've put your finger on the issue with this quote: "Once it returns, the system considers the BroadcastReceiver to be no longer active, and thus, its hosting process no longer needed". It implies (although still doesn't explicitly state) that a process can be killed when there are no active components in it. I believe it can still exist as an empty process (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) and the thread would then still exist, but it could all be killed at any time. Correct?

Comment: Correct, no guarantees as such

Comment: I've marked this answer as "correct". Summary: Worker threads are not terminated by the Android system. They will live until: 1) run() finishes or 2) the app process is killed. The app process is highly subject to being killed when there are no more components running in it, so leaving *only* a worker thread running leaves it (and the process overall) subject to being killed quickly. When a process is subject to being killed is a broader topic than discussed here.

Answer (score 1):

> when is the worker thread killed? Is it only killed when the system actively destroys the process?

-> the worker thread is skilled after all its code in `run` function executed. It still run even when your `activity` is destroyed.

> In my case, my worker thread exists as a listener for a Bluetooth connection; when received, it will fire up the desired Activity again. In this situation there is no actively running component (Activity, Service, ContentProvider or BroadcastReceiver). It seems to me that this should work, except that something is killing my worker thread.

To make it works, You need to have a background `service` in this case and make a `soft`/`weak` reference to your `service` from your worker thread or more simple, using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to start any component from your `Service` as:

```
 EventBus.getDefault().post(new BlueToothEvent()); // call in your worker thread
// do something in your service
onBlueToothEventFired(BlueToothEvent  e);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start a thread, it is independent of the parent that started it. In your case, it is your application activity. This means that until the Run method has been fully executed, your thread will live.

If you exit the application (and therefore call the activity's onStop method), the thread will still exist, and you will cause a memory leak. It will eventually get killed by the system if you run out of memory.

Since you mentioned that you created a listener to listen for a Bluetooth connection, your thread probably dies before it receives any event (It is impossible for me to know without any code snippet). It might also crash which would be ending the thread.

Comment: The memory leak only happens when the Thread holds an Activity reference.

Comment: The thread can hold references to things other than an activity, which would cause a leak of said reference

Comment: Clarification: I *want* the worker thread to continue to exist and I am careful not to generate any new ones after it does. Conceptually, at least, that would allow it to accept incoming Bluetooth requests and fire up the relevant Activity when that happens. So there would be no memory leak (as long as I code the worker thread carefully) -- just memory that I intend to retain for the purposes of the worker thread.

Comment: I don't, as it turns out (per my original post). When I call finish() in onCreate() from my one-and-only Activity (and return from onCreate()), there are no more components running in the process and it becomes subject to clean up the system; at some point soon thereafter, the process is killed and the worker thread, along with everything else, disappears. In contrast, if I were to create a Service and use it to create a worker thread, the Service would continue as a component in the process and the process would be much less likely to be killed (as I think you already know :-)).

Comment: Can you post the code of the run method of your thread? There's something I'm missing. A service might not do what you expect either

Comment: Sorry... I delete the code. It wasn't much, though -- just started a worker thread in onCreate() and could see through logging that it was getting killed. My problem is solved for now (I was mostly curious -- not going to move forward with any more development on this, at least at this point). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

There is one main (also called UI) thread in Android. That is the only thread your app uses, unless it starts one explicitly via `Thread.start()`, `AsyncTask.execute()` etc.  All Activities, Services, BroadcastReceivers, etc run all of their lifecycle methods on that main thread.  Notice I included Services-  a Service runs on the main thread unless it starts its own Thread (the exception to that is an `IntentService`, which does run on its own Thread).

A `Thread` you create continues until the `Runnable` its passed returns from its run function (or of course the process is terminated). This can live past the end of the `Activity/Service` it was created by.  However such a Thread would still live in the original instance of the component, and would not be able to access variables of a new instance if one was restarted without a lot of special work (see Loader pattern).

Comment: where did author mention anything that contradicts your statement? he just spawned a thread from onCreate

Comment: @OlegBogdanov I initially misread his question as thinking onCreate launched a thread.  I removed the You're wrong part.